# Using Cysharp's ConsoleAppFramework, is it possible to create an ongoing command "session"?

Tags: c#, .net, console-application

I'd like to use Cysharp's ConsoleAppFramework (https://github.com/Cysharp/ConsoleAppFramework) to build a little utility project for work.

However, this utility does a lot of setup and config; it takes at least 15 seconds to launch and even start running my commands. That's fine and expected.

But I can only run one command at a time. Once you've executed `app.Run()` that's it. There's no way to run a second command without rebuilding the entire app.

Is it possible to write this in such a way that multiple commands are possible in a session-like manner? Launching the console window once, inputting several commands which all use the same dependencies without needing a rebuild?

Many thanks.